# USB keyboard not working on GRUB

Tags: grub2, keyboard

My down arrow key is broken, so I have to use a USB keyboard to select Windows during boot-up.
It works fine when either OS are loaded, but while on grub only the laptop's keyboard works. So I have to press F12 to enter the boot order and select the second one using the USB keyboard (the USB keyboard works in BIOS). As you can imagine this is inconvenient.

How do I get the USB keyboard to work on GRUB (and why does it refuse so but it works in BIOS)?

(My laptop is an Acer Aspire V17 Nitro Black, Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Not an answer, but just a thought, as a workaround, 'Page Up' and 'Page Down' work for me in GRUB. Why not 'Page Down' then up arrow to the selection you want?

Comment: @robosnacks Just tried that. Unfortunately it only takes me to either the top or bottom items, but none in between.